# Command 'ls' not working in command prompt

Tags: windows, command

Command 'ls' not working in windows
Getting an error while executing 'ls'

> 'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Comment: `ls` is aliased to `dir` in Powershell, maybe that's where you've seen it being used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the command `dir` to list all the directories and files in Windows; `ls` is a unix command.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow below steps to fix this

1. download and install git
   https://git-scm.com/downloads.
2. After git installation is completed,navigate to folder where git is installed. Check in C/Program Files Folder.
   Navigate to C:\Program Files\Git\bin
3. Add the above location (C:\Program Files\Git\bin) in path variable in system environment variables.
4. Restart cmd and try to run ls and other Linux commands.

It should work now!!`

Comment: Git bash is not the only bash emulation tool installable but why not

Answer (score 0):

- We don't use ***`ls(List)`*** command in windows.
- Instead of using ***`ls`*** command use ***`dir(Directory)`*** command.
  This command also displays the total number of files and directories
  listed.

NOTE:

We can use ***`ls`*** command in ***`Windows PowerShell`***. It works in PowerShell, shows the files and directories listed.